# How to test GAE datastore statistics

Tags: java, google-app-engine, unit-testing

I have some code that uses Google App Engine Datastore statistics, and I would like to test this method. I have the following code in order to test this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

  private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
      new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

  @Before
  public void setUp()
      throws Exception {
    helper.setUp();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    helper.tearDown();
  }

  @Test
  public void getKinds() {
    DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    assertEquals(0, datastoreService.prepare(new Query("yam")).countEntities(withLimit(10)));
    datastoreService.put(new Entity("yam"));
    datastoreService.put(new Entity("yam"));
    Iterable<Entity> kinds = datastoreService.prepare(new Query("__Stat_Kind__")).asIterable();
    System.out.println("In 'getKinds'");
    for (Entity kind : kinds) {
      System.out.println(kind.getProperty("kind_name").toString());
    }
  }
}
```

I am expecting this to print

> In 'getKinds'
>   yam

But I am only getting

> In 'getKinds'

Am I missing something in my code, or is there another way to test datastore statistics? Thanks.

Reference links:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/stats

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your datastore is consistent by the time you check?

The datatstore first commits your put by commiting it to the "main" table, and will then "apply" that change to push it to other tablets/indexes....

your put returns after the commit part, not necessarily after the Apply part, which could explain why your kind seems to be empty right after putting in an entity.

you can either do a "while" and check how many entities you have and go forward once you "yam" is in there, or simply do it with ancestor queries to force strong consistency

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#put(com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity)

Put will create the entity right away. It is only if I have an open transaction will "it [be] up to the caller to commit or rollback". I will try it with a transaction though and let you know.

Comment: So I tried adding to a transaction and then committing, but it did not work for me.

Comment: It's not just a matter of transactionnal or "put".  It's how the datastore is handled on the backend.  Look at this article (https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write)  and check the difference between commit and apply.  We ran in the same problems, but we were trying to delete.  

you just need to "force" synchronicity by doing something that'll FORCE the apply (going in the datastore viewer, doing an ancestor query, or simply waiting for the eventual consistency to kick in).